# Show subcategories in a parent category Magento2.1

Tags: category, magento-2.1, submenu

Does anyone have an idea how to show a list of subcategories with a link and image on a parent category.

So when I click a parent category to show all subcategories including the one in the third subcategory. 
[image]

It's maybe good to mention that I also have created a static block for that.
[image]

I found some tutorials including this [one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=itJcSCUHtPQ) on how to add a list of subcategories on a category page but these are all for magento 1.x I need it to be for magento 2.1.

I need a step by step tutorial, please.